# Whats the difference between Scanner(new File) and Scanner(new FileInputStream)?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I observed, `Scanner` when used for file reading works with both the arguments : `File` and `FileInputStream`.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("myfile.txt"));
```

and

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("myfile.txt"));
```

However, I don't know the difference between these two definitions.
Are there any performance related differences ?
Which one to prefer?

Anybody please explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `Scanner(File file)` source code:

```
public Scanner(File source) 
    throws FileNotFoundException
{
    this((ReadableByteChannel)(new FileInputStream(source).getChannel())); 
}
```

The framework will create the `FileInputStream` based on the `File` instance.

After following the source of each path, it will invoke this constructor:

```
private Scanner(Readable source, Pattern pattern) {
    if (source == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("source");
    if (pattern == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("pattern");
    this.source = source;
    delimPattern = pattern;
    buf = CharBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE);
    buf.limit(0);
    matcher = delimPattern.matcher(buf);
    matcher.useTransparentBounds(true);
    matcher.useAnchoringBounds(false);
    useLocale(Locale.getDefault());
}
```

In performance terms, you should not aware of this because JIT will improve the performance at execution time for you. The performance should only matter when you spot a line being a bottleneck by usage of a profiler.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this not exactly right, `Scanner` can get a `File` and it can get an `InputStream`

`Scanner` is not only designed for files.

also, `FileInputStream` extends `InputStream` so it can also be passed to the scanner as a simple `InputStream`.

actually the constructor that receives `File`, converts it to `FileInputStream` so basically its just for faster coding

Bottom line: there is no performance difference